# syntax error in creating a string that contains a variable wrapped in nested quotes

Tags: php, string, double-quotes

this cause error:

```
$xml .= "\t<team id=\"$team['id']\"";
```

this doesn't cause error:

```
$xml .= "\t<team id=\"\"";
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either remove the single quotes:

```
$xml .= "\t<team id=\"$team[id]\"";
```

Or you can use the curly brackets inside double quoted strings using one of the following syntax:

```
$xml .= "\t<team id=\"{$team['id']}\"";
$xml .= "\t<team id=\"${team['id']}\"";
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (scroll down to the "variable parsing" section).

Few more examples:

```
echo "$team[id]";
echo "{$team['first name']}"; // e.g. when there are spaces in key names
echo "{${getVarName()}}";     // e.g. when we cannot use $ directly
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$xml .= "\t<team id=\"$team[id]\"";
```

See how I removed the single quotes around the id.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$xml .= "\t<team id=\"".$team['id']."\"";
```

Or you can use the curly brackets like this

```
$xml .= "\t<team id=\"{$team['id']}\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$xml .= "\t<team id='".$team['id']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the $team['id'] more than the double quotes.

Have you tried:

```
$xml .= "\t<team id=\"".$team['id']."\"";
```

Comment: by doing this the \t will no longer be interpreted as a tab space

Comment: totally true, changing to double quotes again.